# How to change the colour of a button whilst it is being pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I've designed a GUI for a text based adventure game. I need to do some final tweaks to make sure it works smoothly.

I have several buttons (New Game, Exit Button etc.) which are represented by images. I've set the background colour of those button to #073a64 so they would match the colour of the top bar.
[Image of Top Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKMgP.png)

However, when the button is pressed, it turn white / grey for the duration of the press. Is it possible to set  / change the colour of the button whilst it is being pressed?

```
from tkinter import *
trialGUI = Tk()
trialGUI.geometry('710x320')
trialGUI.title("Test GUI")
trialGUI.configure(background='#073a64')
trialGUI.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
trialGUI.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


trialButton = Button(trialGUI, bg='#073a64', height = 10, width = 20)
trialButton.grid()

trialGUI.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
activebackground="color"
```

Hence it should be:

```
trialButton = Button(trialGUI, bg='#073a64', height = 10, width = 20, activebackground="red")
```

This will color the button in red whilst is pressed